# How to improve my RegEx to get the text before the pattern?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

For example I have the next text:

```
Hello, my name is %{John}.
```

Now, I want to take all text **before** `%{John}`. For this I'm using the next RegEx:

```
.+?(?=(?<=%{)[^%]*(?=}))
```

It works, but it includes `%{` this part too. I do not need that. How can I take whole text, but exclude `%{`?

Comment: Why not [`s.split("%{").first`](http://ideone.com/OrwRvf)?

Comment: Why not `s.split('%').first`. There's no need for `{`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
/.+(?=\%\{.*\})/
```

see http://www.rubular.com/r/YHcuSxMIA8

Comment: This will return `Hello, my %{Name} is` with the `Hello, my %{Name} is %{John}.` input. See http://ideone.com/R2Hmm4.

Comment: @J.Doe just made a small update, have a look. And there's no rush to accept an answer (but definitely do pick one at some point). Another better answer may just be around the corner.

Comment: @WiktorStribizew oh. not sure if my answer is sufficient for the OP, but nonetheless I'll have a look at improving it (if I can). Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions should be as simple as possible to accomplish the task. When you add complexity you increase the likelihood it will break in an unexpected way.

Here's where I'd start:

```
'Hello, my name is %{John}.'[/^(.+)%/, 1] # => "Hello, my name is "
```

All that does is specify to start at the beginning of the line and capture everything up to `%`. Nothing else should be necessary.